# Spring boot 2+ Could not Autowire. There is more than one bean of 'UserDetailsService'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, userdetailsservice

Hello Everyone i'm new in spring security and jwt. I'm implementing Jwt in my spring boot project to secure user login and i'm using spring boot 2.1.5 
and i don't know much about new bean restriction in spring  boot 2+ . 
I need some help .. here i'm trying to @Autowired UserDetailsService and code run fine ..and result is also fine.. but intellij shows error at

> @Autowired UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService

saying ... Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of UserDetailsService type.

Can anyone explain me what what happens wrong here why i can't autowired and why and what are the Autowired restriction in spring boot 2+ ?

And thanks in advance

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService; // here i got error only

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/user/add", "/generate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

my customUserDetailService is

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username does't exists");
        }

    }
}
```

My JwtController class which expose restend point to generate jwt token

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class JwtController {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailService jwtUserDetailService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/generate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtRequest.getUsername(),
                    jwtRequest.getPassword()));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVAILD_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = jwtUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(jwtRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtUtils.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }
}
```

My JwtFilter Class

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailService jwtUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtUtils.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtils.validate(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
               SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Other thing as just normal like entity, repository, and some secured restend points

Comment: Seems you have created two components of UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @PratikAmbani Nope just one and everything is running fine

Comment: It seems that `spring-boot-starter-security` includes some default implementation of `UserDetailsService`. You can add `@Primary` annotation on your `JwtUserDetailService` to tell Spring that it must use your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UserDetailsService was provided by spring. 
To Autowire you need to configure it with.

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService getUserDetails(){
   return new JwtUserDetailService(); // Implementation class
}
```

If you are not interested in Bean Configuration.
you can autowire JwtUserDetailService directly.

```
@Autowired
private JwtUserDetailService jwtUserDetailsService;
```

Comment: thanks i got it but yesterday i was tried this and my token got generated but when i used that token to retrieve data i got an error saying invalid token .. but now it is working fine don't know why :D

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error in another context. The reason was the Idea don´t know which bean of type 'UserDetailsService' to use.
My solution is through annotation **Qualifier**:

```
@Qualifier("beanNameWhichYouWantUse")
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
```

If use Idea: give mouse point on the error, select from context menu:

```
"More actions" -> "Add qualifier"
```

[image]

**and finally select the bean**

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration
```